# MySQL query using calculation within sum with field from different table

Tags: php, mysql

I have the following query that I need to use to sum a column in a table, but then I need to multiple it by CONTRACT_PERCENTAGE. CONTRACT_PERCENTAGE is stored in a different table than royalties, called isrc_codes. Both tables share the TRACK_ISRC column. Is there a way I can get the CONTRACT_PERCENTAGE from isrc_codes and use it to put in the sum calculation?

```
$add = mysqli_query($con,"SELECT sum(DISTRIBUTED_AMOUNT / EXCHANGE_RATE * CONTRACT_PERCENTAGE) FROM royalties WHERE BUNDLE_ARTIST = '".$row['artistname']."'");         
while($addamount = mysqli_fetch_array($add)) {              
echo '<td>$' . number_format($addamount[0], 2, '.', '') . '</td>';          
}
```

Comment: You need to read about SQL injection.. (and joins for you problem)

Comment: I know about sql injection, I use prepared statements for any updating or inserting, but maybe there is more to it. This code is only accessible on my admin side and is not accessible to the public

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this query..

```
"SELECT sum(r.DISTRIBUTED_AMOUNT / r.EXCHANGE_RATE * i.CONTRACT_PERCENTAGE) FROM royalties r, isrc_codes i WHERE r.TRACK_ISRC = i.TRACK_ISRC AND r.BUNDLE_ARTIST = '".$row['artistname']."'"
```